# Value becomes null after giving it a value in a function

Tags: android, kotlin, null, android-context

I am attempting to create a scanner SDK and have come across a problem where I have created a class variable value within a function which overrides in a different class in Kotlin.

I have tried both the not-null assertion operator and safe call operator in Kotlin. I have tested the various areas of code with the `println` method to prove that this is indeed the case.

I have also tried removing the 'private' modifier.

Note that I have changed some irrelevant names (the changes are obvious).

```
class XYZ : Activity , xyz.abc, def.hjk{

   private var barcodeReader: BarcodeReader? = null

   private var manager: AidcManager? = null

   override fun onCreate()...
   ...
   create(this,
            object: AidcManager.CreatedCallback {
                override fun onCreated(aidcManager: AidcManager?) {
                    manager = aidcManager
                    barcodeReader = manager?.createBarcodeReader()
                    if (manager != null){
                        println("work1")
                        //manager is not null here
                    }
                }

            })

        if (manager != null){
            //manager is null here
            println("work2")
        }
```

I expect `manager` and `barcodeReader` to not be `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the value can be null at that point is because you init it asynchronously. You don't have any guarantee that `AidcManager.CreatedCallback` will be executed before the second if.

```
---`onCreate`---`createAidc`---`secondIf`---------------`call callback here`
                        \                                /
                         ------ some async work here---
```

See also what is printed first - `work2` or `work1`.
So, it is completely normal and expected.